# Why are "autocompleteselect" handlers called before the configured "select" handler?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am building a customized autocomplete widget in which I need to override the default "select" behavior and have it run before any externally attached event handlers.

```
$("#input").autocomplete({
    source: ['A','B','C'],
    select: function() {
        console.log("from config.select");
    }
});
$("#input").bind("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
    console.log("from bind()");
});
```

When I select an element from the resulting autocomplete, the following gets printed to my console:

```
from bind()
from config.select
```

My question is, why? Is there some rationale behind this?  It seems to me that the event handler configured in the settings/config object given to the autocomplete() "constructor" should happen first, and the handlers attached with bind() should happen afterwards.

I realize that I can just use bind() within my plugin to ensure that my event handler is the first one run, but it adds some clutter to the code.

Comment: "Why" it's that way is possibly only answerable by a jQueryUI team member...

Answer (score 0):

That's because behind the scene it uses the `_trigger` function of the `Widget` object.

Check out code excerpt bellow and you'll see that the `callBack` (the function in your options parameter) is called after the normal event trigger (`this.element.trigger`).

```
_trigger: function( type, event, data ) {
    var callback = this.options[ type ];

    event = $.Event( event );
    event.type = ( type === this.widgetEventPrefix ?
        type :
        this.widgetEventPrefix + type ).toLowerCase();
    data = data || {};

    // copy original event properties over to the new event
    // this would happen if we could call $.event.fix instead of $.Event
    // but we don't have a way to force an event to be fixed multiple times
    if ( event.originalEvent ) {
        for ( var i = $.event.props.length, prop; i; ) {
            prop = $.event.props[ --i ];
            event[ prop ] = event.originalEvent[ prop ];
        }
    }

    this.element.trigger( event, data );

    return !( $.isFunction(callback) &&
        callback.call( this.element[0], event, data ) === false ||
        event.isDefaultPrevented() );
}
```

Best regard,
Stéphane.